# $\dim V=\dim W+\dim U$ and the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ proof ex

Tags: linear-algebra

For each of the following pairs $E_1,E_2$ of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, determine $E_1+E_2$ and prove if $E_1\oplus E_2=\mathbb{R}^3$:

$E_1=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x+y+z=0\};E_2=\{(x,y,0):(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\}$

The intersection is zero. However the dimension of $E_2$ is 2 and the dimension of $E_1$ is 2,since a possible basis for $E_2$ is $e_1=(1,00)$ and $e_2=(0,1,0)$

According to the theorem.

$\dim V=\dim W+\dim U$ when W and U are subspaces of V.

However the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not 4.

Questions:

What is going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the intersection is 0? What about $(1,-1,0)$?

Comment: According to what theorem? $\mathrm{span}(e_1), \mathrm{span}(e_2)$ are subspaces of $\mathbf{R}^4$, but $\dim\mathrm{span}(e_1)+\dim\mathrm{span}(e_2)=2\neq4$. $\dim V=\dim W+\dim U$ holds iff $V=W\oplus U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection is $ \ne \{0\}$ !

We have $\{(x,-x,0): x \in \mathbb R \}= E_1 \cap E_2$, thus $E_1+E_2=\mathbb{R}^3$, but $E_1\oplus E_2=\mathbb{R}^3$ is not valid.

Comment: How did you compute the intersection?

Comment: $(x,y,-x-y)=(x,y,0)$, however if $-x-y=0$ then $x=0$, right?

Comment: It should be clear that $\{(x,-x,0): x \in \mathbb R \} \subseteq E_1 \cap E_2$. Now let $(x,y,z) \in E_1 \cap E_2$. Then $x+y+z=0$ and $z=0$. Hence $y=-x$, therefore $(x,y,z)=(x,-x,0)$

Comment: what am I doing wrong with my method?

Comment: What do you mean with "my method" ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have just discovered what I was doing wrong. Mistaken x by y.